# How to duplicate one frame of an animation?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have a punch animation with, let's assume, 5 frames;

the second frame is the punch collision itself. I wanna be able to duplicate this keyframe and move the following frames forward.

I wanna be able to do this when there is a collision. Making the animation slower doesn't work because it would delay the whole frames.

any tips

Comment: Related: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/181903/jump-to-a-specific-frame-in-an-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could pause the animation, wait for a few frames, and then resume it. Animation can be paused by setting [Animator.speed](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-speed.html) to 0. Something like this:

```
public class PunchAnimation : MonoBehaviour {

  public Animator animator;
  public float delay;

  IEnumerator WaitAndResume(Animator animator, float delay) {
    animator.speed = 0;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    animator.speed = 1;
  }

  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c) {
    StartCoroutine(WaitAndResume(animator, delay));
  }

}
```